# Positioning of nodes resembling cities in networkx graph

Tags: python, graph, geolocation, networkx

I am stuck on one problem regarding how to create a small world graph which resembles real world locations. For this example, I am focusing on UK cities and I have a dictionary of cities with their names and coordinates:

```
UKCITIES = {
"London":[51.49999473,-0.116721844],
"Birmingham":[52.47497398,-1.919996787],
"Manchester":[53.50041526,-2.247987103],
"Leeds":[53.83000755,-1.580017539]
...}
```

I am using `networkx`package for generating graphs and I really like the `navigable_small_world` generator as the edges and connections are super nice and traversible and I would love to keep using that.

Problem is how to position and make the nodes resemble those from real world, so London is south of Edinburgh, but not really having connection to it as there are many nodes in between, like Leeds and Manchester.

First step is the generation of the graph `G = nx.navigable_small_world_graph(5, p=1, q=0)` (I used q as 0 to avoid any long distance connections), and then I create a mapping from the cities dictionary to the actual nodes in G, with `city_mapping = {key:randomSample.pop() for key in G.nodes()}`, and proceed with `nx.relabel_nodes(G, city_mapping, copy=False)`.

This causes the graph to look really weird, as the positioning is randomised. I was doing repositioning nodes from the ones that fit the coordinates, but that makes the edges look super weird, as some adjacent nodes were connected and, i.e. London and Edinburgh, and then they preserve that edge which is really ugly on the graph when I visualise it. It looks like this:
[image]

My ideas are to use the `spring` or `fruchterman_reingold_layout` and then maybe find the closest cities in that positioning distribution and assign them, but that seems quite unintuitive and I am wondering that is the best approach here. Or to scale the initial positioning generated by either of those layouts by min/max lat/lon and then try to overlay the things somehow,

To simplify the question, I want to generate a 'semi-realistic' looking graph of UK cities, for which I have coordinates, and have connections between adjacent nodes with some weights that I will later add (that closely resemble the mile distance).  Something as this figure, it can be a gird as well, but to be realistic as far as the physical positioning of cities is concerned. [image]

What is the best approach to handle this?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just put them at their coordinates?

Comment: @Joel there isn't, but when I do that I have two things to be concerned about. First, if using `navigable_small_world` generator, that will case many weird edges, like shown on my first image. Second, if I use a simple graph, I would then have to create all the edges manually. I have tried with that and it makes the things quite ugly and non deterministic, I have to handle many cases (radius, number of edges, what if node is super far away from others), and have bi-directional edges. `navigable_small_world` handles all that so thats why I would love to use that, seems more 'pythonic'.